# Sorting of a list of list of integer

Tags: c#, sorting

How do I sort following list of list of integer based on first value in inner list in C# for example generated list with following code is

```
List<List<int>> Appoitments = new List<List<int>>();
Appoitments.Add(new List<int> { 6, 7 });
Appoitments.Add(new List<int> { 2, 4 });
Appoitments.Add(new List<int> { 8, 12 });
```

> [[6,7],[2,9],[8.12]]

after sorting I want

> [[2,9], [6,7], 8,12]

I want to sort it based on the first value in the inner list.

Comment: `using System.Linq;` `Appoitments.OrderBy(a => a[0]));` Did you try to do a search online for this? I don't know why I answered that because there was no attempted code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ's OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0). You'll need to import `using System.Linq;`

`Appoitments.OrderBy(a => a[0]));`